# Django: ImportError: cannot import name Count

Tags: python, django

I just pulled from my github and tried to setup my application on my Ubuntu (I originally ran my app on a Mac at home).

I re-created the database and reconfigured the settings.py -- also update the template locations, etc.

However, when I run the server "python manage.py runserver" get an error that says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Count
```

I imported the Count in my views.py to use the annotate():

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db.models import Count
from mysite.blog.models import Blog
from mysite.blog.models import Comment
from mysite.blog.forms import CommentForm

def index(request):
    #below, I used annotate()
    blog_posts = Blog.objects.all().annotate(Count('comment')).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    return render_to_response('blog/index.html', 
                             {'blog_posts': blog_posts})
```

Why is not working?

Also, if I remove the "import Count" line, the error goes away and my app functions like normal.

Thanks,
Wenbert

**UPDATE:**

my models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.content

    def was_published_today(self):
            return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comment = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.comment
```

**UPDATE 2**

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    (r'^blog/$','mysite.blog.views.index'),
    (r'^display_meta/$','mysite.blog.views.display_meta'),
    (r'^blog/post/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$','mysite.blog.views.post'),
)
```

Comment: What does your models.py look like?  Do you have a Method/Class Count?

Comment: You are definitely using the same version of Django, yeah?

Comment: What version of Django do you use? Are you sure it IS the latest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're not using Django 1.1. Double check by opening up the Django shell and running

```
import django
print django.VERSION
```

You should see something like `(1, 1, 0, 'final', 0)` if you're using 1.1

Comment: You are right. I get this: (1, 0, 2, 'final', 0). I installed Django using the Synaptic Package Manager in Ubuntu. I will try to uninstall and install the one from the Django website.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my Django and it turns out that your import statement is correct as module structure was changed a bit. Are you sure your Django is of latest version?

Comment: It is not working for me. I get this error:

Could not import mysite.blog.views. Error was: No module named aggregates

Comment: Could you post your urls.py too?

Comment: freiksenet, I added urls.py in my question above